# Is HHG recombination a tunneling event?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, laser

When the electron returns to the ion at the end of its path I understand that it has more kinetic energy than the binding energy of the atom. Does this mean the capture relies on reflection by a classically allowed barrier i.e. an inverse of tunnel ionisation? What does the laser field look like at the end of the short and long trajectories?